# More than one IndexOf possibilities

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I am looking for a way to parse a substring with a few different terminating characters that could possibly be used. Should I be using a different method or is there a way to use regular expressions to sort out the characters?

My current code uses:

```
smallstring = bigstring.substring(bigstring.indexOf("starthere"), bigstring.indexOf("endhere"));
```

The last index can either be "]" or ";" and I need the parser to be able to detect both and terminate the substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String`'s [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method for this, it's the right tool for the job:

```
String[] data = "a,b.c;d".split("[,.;]");
```

In the above example, a string using three different separators (`,.;`) can be split using a single regular expression. The end result, a `String[]` called `data`, will contain all the strings that were separated by the delimiters:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: This ended up working the best, and providing a much better method of parsing my string. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To detect the ending index, you could write

```
int endIndex = Math.min(bigstring.indexOf("]"), bigstring.indexOf(";"));
if(endIndex == -1) { endIndex = bigstring.length(); }
String smallString = bigstring.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: This would have worked had there been both designated characters after the starting index, but it threw an index out of bounds exception when it couldn't fine the semi-colon. Too bad, this would have been the most simple approach. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: @AlexBible I assumed there would be an ending character somewhere in the file. If there isn't, the (updated) code above will still work, with no exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String smallstring = bigstring.replaceAll(".*starthere(.*)endhere.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression.
Here's where you can test it
http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/